# Why is this counting sort in C++ not working?

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, loops, sorting

Why is this counting sort not working?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void countSort(vector<int>& input)
{
    int max = *max_element(input.begin(), input.end());
    vector<int> counter(max + 1);
    vector<int> output;
    for(int i = 0; i < max + 1; ++i)
    {
        counter[i] = 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i)
    {
        counter[input[i]]++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < max  + 1; ++i)
    {
        while(counter[i] > 0)
        {
            output.push_back(counter[input[i]]);
            counter[i]--;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> array = {9, 8, 9, 1, 5, 7, 1, 2};
    countSort(array);
}
```

When I run this code, it just send me an error message,

> The process finished with exit code 1073741819 (0xC0000005)

but I can't understand where the mistake is.

Comment: In your last for-loop, `input[i]` seems to assume that `input` has at least `max+1` elements in it.  But it doesn't.  Typo?

Comment: @DrewDormann in last for loop I just passing through the counter array, that has max+1 elements. What is wrong?

Comment: If you use `g++` or `clang++` add the arguments `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` when compiling. You'll get [something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/eb31oWzsW) when running the program. It's really helpful

Comment: Unrelated: The loop to set all elements in `counter` to `0` isn't needed.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @TedLyngmo why while loop isn't needed? I decrease counter[i] if it more than 0 and when it became 0 I go to the next element.

Comment: @StephenNewell Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: You do `counter[i] = 0;` in the loop but all the elements in `counter` is `0` already.

Comment: _" in last for loop I just passing through the counter array,"_ You have `input[i]` in that loop.  Reading from `input[9]` is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < max  + 1; ++i) ... input[i]` This exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds. `input` doesn't have 10 elements.

Comment: @DrewDormann and how can i solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is in your `push_back`.

```
output.push_back(counter[input[i]]);
```

It should simply be:

```
output.push_back(i);
```

You also do not save the result of the sorted `output` array. You could return it or replace `input`. In my example below, I'm replacing `input`.

Another potential problem is that you are sorting *signed* integers so you should expect negative ones. If you get a negative value now, you'll access your `counter` array out of bounds.

A simple remedy is to check for both the `min` and `max` values first and to subtract `min` from all subscripting in `counter`.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void countSort(std::vector<int>& input) {
    auto[minit, maxit] = std::minmax_element(input.begin(), input.end());
    auto min = *minit;
    auto max = *maxit;
    std::vector<int> counter(max - min + 1);

    for(auto in : input) ++counter[in-min];           // -min offset

    input.clear(); // clearing it to fill with the sorted values

    for(int i = min; i <= max; ++i) {
        for(;counter[i-min] > 0; --counter[i-min]) {  // -min offset
            input.push_back(i);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> array = {9, 8, 9, 1, 5, 7, 1, 2, -10}; // negative value added
    
    countSort(array);

    for(auto v : array) std::cout << v << ' ';
}
```

Output:

```
-10 1 1 2 5 7 8 9 9
```